# Rotate Vec2f line about a non origin point

Tags: opencv, math, vector, rotation, polar-coordinates

In OpenCv lines are defined in polar coordinates, in terms of R and theta. In my case I have found a line in and image, rotated the image, and now I want to know what the value the line would have in the rotated image. In this case I am rotating around a known point which is not the origin.

I know I can simply find the new value for theta by adding the rotation angle, but have no idea how to rotate a polar line, by a non zero point.

So what I am asking really is what is the new value for R going to be if a rotate the line about (Xr, Yr)?

I would note I realise that I could probably just find the line again in the new image but there was a lot of computation involved in finding which line I wanted so if there is a formula I can use to find the new line value that would be preferable.

[image]

Comment: in cartesian coordinates you could subtract the point, rotate around origin and add the point again. Maybe this would work in polar coordinates too, but no idea how to translate in polar coordinates

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a clumsy but reasonably simple way to do this, using the idea of finding the closest point to the line from an arbitrary point. Some diagrams may be able to explain this better:

[image]

Where `C` is the center of rotation, and `Q` is the closest point on the line to it (corresponding to `O` and `P`). Computing `P` and `d` from `r, θ`, we can find `Q` using a vector math formula (available in many geometry textbooks):

[image]

After rotating `d` and `Q` (the latter around `C` - I'll assume you know how to do so):

[image]

Now we just find `P'` using the same method used to find `Q` above, which then trivially gives the new `θ'` and `r'`:

[image]

Notes:

1. Beware that we need `atan2` (available in most languages) instead of `atan`, as the latter will not handle all four quadrants correctly.
2. There is also a special case where the final line passes through `O` at a very small distance, which would lead to errors when computing `θ`. To deal with this situation, we can compute the polar angle of the new direction `d'` and *subtract* 90° (according to the "handed-ness" convention used in the above diagrams). The same caution need not be taken when computing `P`.

Comment: Very nice approach

Comment: @MBo thank you. I welcome any suggestions or better approaches - I simply find that working with Cartesian vectors eliminates many of the special cases in polar coordinates.